# Creating objects with different properties from one class - JAVA

Tags: java, oop

In Java, I have an `abstract class Player` and the two classes `Striker` and `Defender` they both extend the `abstract class Player`. I have an `Interface IAttack` and an `Interface IDefend`. In those 2 interfaces there is the prototype of only one method - the method `shoot`(for the Interface `IAttack`) and the method `tackle`(for the interface `IDefend`). I've implemented the method `shoot`(resp. `tackle`) in the class `Striker`(resp `Defender`).With this hierarchy I can create Strikes, who can only shoot the ball to a given distance. I can create defenders, who can tackle somebody only with a given intensity.

What I want is to be able to create strikers(resp. defenders) who can do different tasks(and not only shoot to a given distance). For example I'd like to  have a striker who can shoot a penalty, a striker who can play with its head etc.

How can I do that? Do I need necessarily to create more classes for the strikers(I mean a class for the strikers who shoot penalties, a class for the striker who play with head). Is there a more elegant way to have strikers who can do multiple tasks?

Comment: Add another attribute for roles then for each Striker object just set the roles that they have...example `Striker.isPenalties()`.

Comment: what does shoot(resp. tackle) mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of ways to implement it.

1) Let another `Stricker` class implement both `IShootPenalty, and IAttack` behavior. You can create individual required interfaces, and let each player object implement appropriate interfaces. Mix and match them as required.

(or)

2) Create boolean flags for each behavior in abstract class, and set the appropriate flags based on required behavior.

```
Stricker.setShootPenality(true);
Striker.setShooter(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

A nice way would be to have all the properties in a different class.
Say for example, a class called `StrikerProperties.java`.
You can have different variables here and set them `true` or `false` depending upon the other characteristics of the player. This will enable you to use this for different objects, and also different classes, in cases you want to make teams and all later.